# Redux store not getting updated

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I need to display an nested array. But I am unable to display the nested list as my redux store is not getting updated. Below is the sample of the structure of the data:

```
{
email: "fgh@gmail.com"
tId: 2
teacherClasses: null
teacherUserRef: 3
user:
{
admin: null
firstName: "fgh"
id: 3
lastName: "fgh"

}}
```

I am unable to display anything which is inside user.

below is the code:

Reducer:

```
import { ACTION_TYPES } from "../actions/teacher";
const initialState = {
    list: []
   
}


export const teacher = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL:
            
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [
                    ...action.payload]
            }
        case ACTION_TYPES.FETCHBYID:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [action.payload]
            }

        case ACTION_TYPES.CREATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [...state.list, action.payload]
            }

        case ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: state.list.map(x => x.id == action.payload.id ? action.payload : x)
            }

        case ACTION_TYPES.DELETE:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: state.list.filter(x => x.id != action.payload)
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Component page:

Teacher.js:

```
const Teacher = ({ ...props }) => {
    const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("teacher call")
        
        props.fetchAllTeacher()
        console.log(props.teacherList)
    }, [currentId])//componentDidMount

    return (
        <div className="site-layout-background" style={{ padding: 24, textAlign: 'center' }}>
        <Space direction="vertical" align="center">
                
                        <TableContainer>
                            <Table>
                                <TableHead >
                                    <TableRow>
                                        <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>Email</TableCell>

                                        <TableCell></TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>

                                    {
                                        
                                         props.teacherList.map((record, index) => {
                                        return (<TableRow key={index} hover>
                                            <TableCell>{record.email}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>{record.user.firstName}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>
                                                <ButtonGroup variant="text">
                                                    <Button icon={<DeleteOutlined />} onClick={() => onDelete(record.user.id)}></Button>
                                                </ButtonGroup>
                                            </TableCell>
                                            

                                        </TableRow>)
                                    })}
                                </TableHead>
                                <TableBody>
                                    
                                </TableBody>
                            </Table>
                        </TableContainer>

            </Space>
            </div>
            
        
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    teacherList: state.teacher.list,
    userList: state.user.list
})

const mapActionToProps = {
    fetchAllTeacher: actions.fetchAll,
    deleteUser: actions1.Delete
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(Teacher);
```

Action creator:

```
import api from "./api";

export const ACTION_TYPES = {
    CREATE: 'CREATE',
    UPDATE: 'UPDATE',
    DELETE: 'DELETE',
    FETCH_ALL: 'FETCH_ALL',
    FETCHBYID: 'FETCHBYID'
}



export const fetchAll = () => dispatch => {
    api.teacher().fetchAll()
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL,
                payload: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
export const fetchById = (id) => dispatch => {
    api.teacher().fetchById(id)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCHBYID,
                payload: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const create = (data, onSuccess) => dispatch => {

    api.teacher().create(data)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.CREATE,
                payload: res.data
            })
            onSuccess()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const update = (id, data, onSuccess) => dispatch => {

    api.teacher().update(id, data)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE,
                payload: { id, ...data }
            })
            onSuccess()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const Delete = (id, onSuccess) => dispatch => {
    api.teacher().delete(id)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.DELETE,
                payload: id
            })
            onSuccess()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

I am getting an error saying firstName is undefined.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Recommendation**

Since you are using functional component, you should use `react-redux` hooks like `useSelector`, `useDispatch`.

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"

...
teacherList = useSelect(state => state.teacher.list)
userList = useSelect(state => state.user.list)

const dispatch = useDispatch()
...
{
dispatch(actions.fetchAll(...))
dispatch(actions1.Delete(...))
}
```

- **Problem**

First, you don't need to set `currentId` as a dependency of `useEffect`.

When dependency is an empty list, the callback will only be fired once, similar to `componentDidMount`.

Second, `fetchAllTeacher` is an asynchronous action which means you need to wait until all teachers are fetched successfully.

So you need to add a lazy loading feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use useSelector, useDispatch.. But is that the one causing issues?

Comment: I recommend to use it. It's not mandatory. Btw, please share `console.log(props.teacherList)` result.

Comment: thanks for your time. below is the result:  `0:
email: "pashmina@gmail.com"
tId: 1
teacherClasses: null
teacherUserRef: 2
user:
admin: null
firstName: "pashmina"
id: 2
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

1:
email: "vijeth@gmail.com"
tId: 2006
teacherClasses: null
teacherUserRef: 1013
user:
admin: null
firstName: "vjv"
id: 1013

__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

2:
email: "shyamal.bhat@gmail.com"
tId: 2007
teacherClasses: null
teacherUserRef: 1014
user:
admin: null
firstName: "lamini"
id: 1014`

Comment: there is always delay in result

Comment: Try {record.user?.firstName}

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your redux store is not getting updated is because you must dispatch the actions. The correct signature for `mapDispatchToProps` is:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    fetchAllTeacher: () => dispatch(actions.fetchAll()),
    deleteUser: (id) => dispatch(actions.Delete(id)),
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Teacher);
```

BUT the there is a better way. You are actually mixing two paradigms, and while the above will work, you should use redux hooks, since you have created a functional component and you are already using the `useEffect` hook.

It could work like this:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"

const Teacher = ({ ...props }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("teacher call")
        
        const teachers = props.fetchAllTeacher();
        // dispatch the action that will add the list to the redux state
        dispatch(actions.fetchAll(teachers));
    }, [currentId]);
    
    // fetch the teacher list from redux store

    const teacherList = useSelector(state => state.teacher.list);
    return (...);
}
```

Consider moving the selector definition `state => state.teacher.list` to its own module so that you can reuse it in other components and update it in one place if the structure of your store changes.

It looks like no actions were getting dispatched in your code, so the problem was not due to nesting of the data. You can have nested data in your state without a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will make sure will not mix. I am dispatching the actions too. I have edited my question. Please check